# data-target opens modal with page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-blade

I am recently trying bootstrap modals, i have sucessfuly create a modal but i have it in same page as my "main site" is it possible thath data-target opens a site where this module i declared because i realy want to separate such things from other code.

Thath how i open a modal now:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegister">
```

i am using laravel4/blade templating to i tryed like thath:

```
data-target="pages.register"
```

but it seems thath now the way it should work....

Comment: Try to reformulate your question. Isn't very clear. If you can't tell exacly what you need, becomes harder to help you. Try to make a single question and put where you have gone so far. I'll be glad to help you (as everyone else here) but the question has to be as simple as possible. :D

Comment: Currently i have modal code in the same file as my main site, i want to have modal(separate it) in another file and thath i would be able to open with data-target but i dont know how i can do that.